# Get value from UIDatePicker before animations stops

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

Does someone know if it is possible to get value from `UIDatePicker` before its animation stops?
I tried using `UIControlValueChanged` event but it is fired after the animation, when picker is "settled" on final position. 
The result I want to achieve is that when user spins pickers wheel and presses "ok" button while it is spinning, the value that is in the middle of the picker should be selected.

Or if that is impossible maybe there is a way to select when animation started so I can disable "ok" button and force user to pick something before he can accept?

Comment: I had the same issue there is no way as far as I was able to find. I am guessing your OK button clears a value and that causses a crash?

Comment: No, it is not as spectacular as crash :) I'm using a 'date' property and it still contains previous value (or initial).

Comment: Yea that's why you should have a label with the value so the user sees they did not update. I searched long and hard but no other solution.